# Cucumber Scenario Outline - Execution Flow

Tags: groovy, cucumber

I am working with Cucumber and Groovy in Katalon Studio. I have the cucumber feature file where it has **Multiple Scenario Outlines** as mentioned below.

When I run the cucumber feature file, it should run the TestCase1 of first section in the scenario outline along with the steps and TestCase1 of second section in scenario outline.

But, it is running the first section of feature file TestCase1 and TestCase2 first. That means it is just loggining with given credentials and closing the browser.

For reference, below mentioned the step definition code also.

**Cucumber Feature File:**

```
@Login1
Feature: Title of your feature
  I want to use this template for my feature file

@Login1   `**SECTION ONE**`
Scenario Outline: Login into GMP Application
Given running indicator flag
And User is on GMP Application Login Screen
When User enters the in the Login
And User enters the in the password
And User clicks on the ok button
Then User logged in successful at Home Screen
Examples:
| atid   | pwd1    | runind |   -> Header
| nm1013 | test01g |   Y    |   -> TestCase1
| nm0313 | test02g |   Y    |   -> TestCase2

@Login1     `**SECTION TWO**`
Scenario Outline: Click on the Create Inquiry Menu Item
Given User is on GMP Home Screen
When user click on the Inquiry menu item
And select the billing mode should be
And user click create inquiry item from the heading
Then it should displays create inquiry pagef
Examples:
|   contract     |    -> Header
| GS00T07NSD0007 |    -> TestCase1
| GS00T07NSD0007 |    -> TestCase2
```

**Step Definition**

```
@Given(“running indicator flag (.*)”)
def run_indicator_flag(String ind1) {
println "Passing Indicator " + ind1
}

@And(“User is on GMP Application Login Screen”)
def user_on_GMP_Application_Login_Screen() {
boolean store2a
WebUI.openBrowser(’’)
WebUI.navigateToUrl(‘https://URL’, FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)
}

@When(“User enters the (.*) in the Login”)
def user_enter_userid_in_the_Login(String uid) {
WebUI.setText(findTestObject(‘Object Repository/ORTC01/Page_/input_userid’), 
uid, FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)
}

@And(“User enters the (.*) in the password”)
def User_enters_the_in_the_password(String pwd5) {
WebUI.setText(findTestObject(‘Object 
Repository/ORTC01/Page_/input_password’), pwd5, 
FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)
}
```

Comment: your assumption is wrong. The two scenariooutlines are separate and independent of each other. You could look at merging the two together into one.

Comment: **Thank You, Grasshopper**. So, it means that, Do I need to have only one step in the whole feature file ? Can't I separate the feature file into separate sections ? For example, I have thirty lines of steps in the feature file. In the first 10 lines, I am passing some parameters. And, at 25th line, I will pass some parameters. So, how can I have single scenario outline with such a huge 30 lines of feature file ? For reading also, it would be difficult. **Please suggest.**

Comment: **Thank You, halfer**

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot connect scenarios in Cucumber. Each scenario is a separate test that starts from nothing, does something and then resets back to nothing.

Secondly a scenario outline is just a way to write several scenarios in a more compact form. Each set of examples in an outline causes a single scenario to be created and run. I would strongly recommend you avoid using Scenario Outlines

Good scenarios describe WHAT is being done without getting into HOW things are done. Your scenarios are full of HOW things are done which makes them complex and very difficult to work with. You should push all the HOW down into your step definitions (or better still helper methods called by your step definitions.

If you do these things you will be able to write scenarios that will look something like

```
Scenario: Create a billing enquiry
  Given I have a bill
  And I am logged in
  When I enquire about my bill
  Then ...
```

Note: How the above scenario is much shorter and has no detail about HOW you do anything.